# Similar Patterns Recognition

Tags: c#, vb.net, algorithm, search, find

I'm trying to automate a workflow process with a software to help the operator.
The operator looks at a chart build from a byte sequence read from some binary log files, and if he recognizes some specific patterns(in form or shape of the line; chart is a 2d line), he has to do something.

I'm already able to aquire the logs an find these patterns if they arematching exactly (I'm using a string search algo), but I have no idea how to detect patterns that are only partial matches, or similiar.
Some typical case could be:

1 the pattern that I'm looking for is present but with only some byte alerated ie
1a-2b-e1-1b-1a-8c instead of 1a-2b-e1-0b-1a-8c

2 the pattern that I'm looking for is present but with with an offset like
1a-2b-e1 instead of 10-2a-e0

3 a mix of 1 and 2

Anyone known a way to do that? I'm working in vb.net but any input would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a few things maybe worth looking at:

let's say our pattern is
01-23-45-67-89-A1

and our possible hit in the binary log looks like this:
02-23-46-66-00-89-A1

what happens when we calculate the absolute difference?
01-00-01-01-89-18

let's say we define a threshold of 01 per byte and a notation of XX for an accepted byte and RR for a rejected byte... what would be accepted and rejected?
XX-XX-XX-XX-RR-RR

now the index where the RR is beginning is interesting ... what happens if we skip this byte in the log?
02-23-46-66-00-89-A1 becomes
02-23-46-66-89-A1

abs difference again
01-00-01-01-00-00

acceptance would now be good...
XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX

on the other way around, we could have a byte missing in the log, which leads to the variant that you can try and insert the pattern byte of the first RR in place of the first RR... example:

let's say our pattern again is
01-23-45-67-89-A1

and our possible hit in the binary log looks like this:
02-23-46-88-A1-00

abs diff
01-00-01-21-18-A1

acceptance
XX-XX-XX-RR-RR-RR

now we try and insert... so our log virtually looks like this
02-23-46-67-88-A1-00

abs diff again...
01-00-01-00-01-00

acceptance
XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX

of course there may be more types of errors ... like a one off that neither skipping or inserting will fix ...

calculate the original difference ... plus the difference if you skip and the difference if you insert ... take the best result (read: the one with least RR bytes)

you will need to find suitable values for the threshold and how many skips/insertions you want to allow ... or instead of a binary acceptance you could use some metric for similarity

Comment: I think I'll get your point;It seem would work, once tuned, I'm wondering if I can adapt the the boyer-moore algo that I actualy use for exact matching... I'll make some experiments, an report.  What about metric for similarity?

Comment: a metric is a way of making things comparable ... this can be a function that tunrs your matching candidate into a numeric value, comparable to other matching candidates or to a thrshold value ... for the above algo, you coiuld simply sum all absolute diff bytes and divide by pattern length, or you could ignore differences below the threshold, summing only RRs ...this way you could allow the user to fine tune metric params and give a threshold to make it work for their needs, while your code still does the same calculations but with different coefficients

Comment: I was wondering if there are any benefit to use machine learning, like ML.net,  to this task. Anyone have any experience in similar task?

Comment: I'll also post some more complex example of data

Comment: I'm  trying to implement what you have explain, but I missed something: How can I find the possible hit? I mean if I can't use the first or the last value of the pattern as exact string search does, how can I do that?

Comment: (almost) each byte in your log is a possible starting location for your pattern... so... a for-each loop maybe?

Comment: Yes, I already  done. And it's amazing!! Fast and precise.